# make GUI to take an image and do hitogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter, image-processing

i need to do GUI
input image and output histogram using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

# for make a button to find the image 
 
def image1():
    curr_directory = os.getcwd()
    responce = messagebox.showinfo( "This is information massage", "By clicking okay you will upload  Image")
    Label( frame1,text = responce)
    frame1.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir= curr_directory, title="Select image")
    my_label = Label(frame1, text=frame1.filename)
    my_label.grid()
    return frame1.filename
my_btn1 = Button(frame1, text ="Upload image", command= image1,  borderwidth= 5)
my_btn1.grid()
frame2 = LabelFrame(tab1, text="Histogram ", padx=200, pady=20)
frame2.pack(padx=1, pady=10)

# to make histogram take the image from the previous button 

def make_histogram(image, bins=256):
    # array with size of bins, set to zeros
    histogram = np.zeros(bins)
    # loop through pixels and sum up counts of pixels
    for pixel in image:
        histogram[pixel] += 1
    # return our final result
    return histogram

my_btn2 = Button(frame2, text ="histogram", command= make_histogram,  borderwidth= 5)
my_btn2.grid()
```

but i found the following error TypeError: make_histogram() missing 1 required positional argument: 'image'

Comment: you're missing the tkinter import. -- please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre]. -- this is a basic programming issue. you need to understand what tkinter does with a function that you pass as the `command` parameter.

Comment: tkinter are alreaady imported and worked well my proplem is to use the image from the image1 to make_histogram function so i found TypeError: make_histogram() missing 1 required positional argument: 'image'

Comment: that error stems from tkinter trying to call your function, but tkinter doesn't have the data that your function expects. do you understand that?